# Assign full text file path to a variable and use variable as file path in sh file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to create a shell script for logs and trying to append data into a text file. I have write this sample "test.sh" code for testing:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
touch /home/sample.txt

SPTH = '/home/sample'.txt

echo "MY LOG FILE" >> "$SPTH"
echo "DUMP started at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> /home/sample.txt
echo "DUMP finished at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> /home/sample.txt
```

but in above code all lines are working correct except one line of code i.e.

```
echo "MY LOG FILE" >> "$SPTH"
```

It is giving error:

```
test.sh: line 6: : No such file or directory
```

I want to replace this full path of file "/home/sample.txt" to variable "$SPATH".

I am executing my shell script using

```
sh test.sh
```

What I am doing wrong.

Comment: What about for line 4? It would have thrown an error for sure too!

Comment: No spaces around an assignment, should be `SPTH='/home/sample'.txt`

Comment: if you put in a line,  echo $SPTH, you'll see what it really contains.  This should be enlightening :-)

Comment: And why do you have ".txt" outside the single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable assignments in `bash` shell does not allow you to have *spaces* within. It will be actually interpreted as command with `=` and the subsequent keywords as arguments to the first word, which is wrong.

Change your code to

```
SPTH="/home/sample.txt"
```

That is the reason why `SPTH` was not assigned to the actual path you intended it to have. And you have no reason to have single-quote here and *excluding* the extension part. Using it fully within double-quotes is absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks, its working. I removed space from = and write is as SPTH='/home/sample'.txt

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the command line is that the first *token* is a command, tokens are separated by whitespace.  So:

```
SPTH = '/home/sample'.txt
```

Has the command as `SPTH`, the second token is `=`, and so on.  You might think this is daft, but most shells behave like this for historical reasons.

So you need to remove the whitespace:

```
SPTH='/home/sample'.txt
```